# Overlay component with alpha, redraw when controls under it redraw

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, alpha

I created a custom control which I want to use to overlay part of my form with status information on demand. It should display a text and have a background color depending on the type of information. Here is the still incomplete code.

```
public partial class StatusPanel : UserControl
{
    public enum PanelStyle
    {
        Info,
        Warning,
        Error
    }

    public PanelStyle Style { get; set; }

    public StatusPanel()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.imgGreen = new Bitmap(256, 256, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        using(Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(this.imgGreen))
        {
            g.Clear(Color.Transparent);
            Brush bg = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(200, Color.Green));
            g.FillRectangle(bg, 0, 0, 256, 256);
        }

        this.imgYellow = new Bitmap(256, 256, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        using(Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(this.imgYellow))
        {
            g.Clear(Color.Transparent);
            Brush bg = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(10, Color.Yellow));
            g.FillRectangle(bg, 0, 0, 256, 256);
        }
    }

    protected readonly Font font = new Font("Arial", 12.0F);

    protected readonly Brush textBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);

    protected readonly Image imgGreen;

    protected readonly Image imgYellow;

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.ExStyle |= 0x00000020; //WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
            return cp;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        // do not draw background
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
        e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBilinear;
        e.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;

        Image img = GetImage();

        e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, 0, 0, this.Width, this.Height);

        e.Graphics.DrawString("ABC", this.font, this.textBrush, 1.0F, 1.0F);
    }

    protected Image GetImage()
    {
        return (this.Style == PanelStyle.Info) ? this.imgGreen : this.imgYellow;
    }
}
```

This works quite fine. But when I put some buttons on a form and one of this controls infront of them, they will "overdraw" when the mouse moves over the button and the highlight effects redraws them.

How will my component be notified that it needs to redraw because underlying control have redrawn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

register a paint-handler to all controls under `Parent.Control` and a handler for `Parent.ControlAdded` that registers your paint-handler

something like this:

```
private void myDummyUserControl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var uc = (DummyUserControl)sender;
    uc.Parent.ControlAdded += new ControlEventHandler(Parent_ControlAdded);
    foreach (Control c in uc.Parent.Controls)
    {
        if (uc == c)
            continue;
        c.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(c_Paint);
    }
}

void c_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    //checks & paint stuff here
}

void Parent_ControlAdded(object sender, ControlEventArgs e)
{
    e.Control.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(c_Paint);
}
```

//edit

not sure if you need to use recursion to go down the tree of child controls and need to add handlers on those too ...

Comment: So you mean like telling all other components when they are painted to tell my status panel to repaint? Maybe with a manual check if the component boundaries overlap?

Comment: basically, yes. of course you can make this a bit more complex, by registering eventhandlers for relocation or resizing, and register or unregister your paint-handler based on a check for overlapping boundaries

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42 Okay, this helps when I invalidate my control in the paint event of the other controls if they intersect. There still is a little flicker effect. Is there a way to use double buffering in this context?

Comment: @Zool sorry, i never used doublebuffering in a .net environment, but to reduce unwanted effects, you could try to repaint only the region that needs repainting ... see the PaintEventArgs ClipRectangle and Graphics Properties

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42 Problem is I do neither know the logic to paint the other controls nor do I want to. Image a normal Winforms.Button under my control. In its paint-event I now check if it is under my control and if it is, my control invalidates to repaint. But I cannot stop the button from drawing itself. In fact that is needed because I need a full drawn button to have my alpha control painted right. So currently I have no clue how to minimize such effects. The current solution might be good enough. Otherwise I will add a new question in the future. Thanks so far.

Comment: @Zool you don't need to paint that button ... when your handler is called, the button is already painted to the graphics object ... try the following code as a demo handler and see what happens: `e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.FromArgb(127,Color.Red)), e.ClipRectangle.Location, new Point(e.ClipRectangle.X + e.ClipRectangle.Width, e.ClipRectangle.Y + e.ClipRectangle.Height));`